# Isomorphic image of a simple algebra is simple

Tags: abstract-algebra

I would like to prove the following theorem:

> If $E$ is a simple algebra (over a field $K$), $F$ is an algebra (over $K$) and $h: E \to F$ is an isomorphism, then $F$ is simple.

Of course the zero ideal and $h(E)= F$ are ideals, but how to prove that there are no other ideals?

Comment: Ideals in $E$ and $F$ correspond via $h$.

Comment: Let $I$ be an ideal of $F$; then $h^{-1}{I}$ is an ideal of $E$. Hence…

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $I$ be an ideal of $F$; then $h^{-1}(I)$ is an ideal of $E$. Hence… Since $I=h(h^{-1}(I))$, we conclude that…